# Session exists even after destroying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a session variable with name session[:computerid] and while login it's set to "comp--001". While sign out i am deleting session like as follows

```
 session.delete(:computerid)
```

But after doing that also if i debug session[:computerid] it's showing value "comp--001".

My session_store.rb file has the following code:

```
 Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_sample_app_session', :domain=>:all
```

Could you suggest me a solution to solve this?

Comment: try `session[:computerid]=nil` or if you want to reset whole session then in `destroy` method `reset_session` call this, and your whole session will get `deleted`

Comment: its not working sontya

Answer (score 0):

Could you try setting it to `nil`? Like:

```
session[:computerid] = nil
```

This is the most common pattern in rails.

Hope it helps!

Good luck!

Comment: I am getting undefined method `delete!' for #<ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0xb4589d0>

Comment: It's strange, because in that case, the `nil` value should be stored under the `:computerid` key. Please check example from [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash), where `:current_user_id` is deleted by assigning `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails doesn't know what you want to keep or not when a user signs-out.

Say for example you have a session[:language] that is useful for every user, even anonymous ones. You wouldn't want to erase it to display the default language after the user has gone through the trouble of selecting one in particular.

So, delete the session objects you need to, like session[:user]=nil and keep the rest. If you have a lot of them to delete, make yourself a logout helper.

If you know you can swipe the whole session, use the reset_session